# how to save password in pycharm secure (not-shown)?

Tags: python

For automation testing I need to save the password and username in Pycharm as fixture (pytest).
I cannot hash or encrypt the password because my secure system hashes the password by itself. But then I face a problem - my password is printed in log output and is open to other people in project as fixture. In log output I fixed this problem with the parameter 'set +x'. How can I save the password hidden or shown as asterisk or something like this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am not too familiar with pytest, is the password stored by the ide or somewehere in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can "hide" it with class wrapper, for example:

```
import logging

class Password(object):

    def __init__(self, password):
        self._password = password

    def __call__(self):
        return self._password

    def __str__(self):
        return '*' * len(self._password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Password(password='******')"


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
password = Password('p@ssw0rd')

# password masked
>>> print password
********

>>> logging.info('log in: user = John, password = %s', password)
INFO:root:log in: user = John, password = ********

>>> password
Password(password='******')

# unmasked, real password
>>> print password()
p@ssw0rd
```

Comment: Explain with comments. Ex: __call__ does what. This way your answer will be great. Thanks for the hack.

Comment: Python's `logging` is powerful and `filters` will help you achieve your goals. Please refer https://gist.github.com/acdha/9238791 and https://www.relaxdiego.com/2014/07/logging-in-python.html#configuring-your-loggers for the best logging

Comment: Thank you, Ajay2588, for useful tips! =)